# observe changes to array of structs

Tags: swift

How do you observe additions/deletions to an array of structs?

If it were an array of classes, you could make the array dynamic and use KVO.
With structs you run into problems with @objc or @objcMembers in iOS 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you control the definition of the array? If so, you can add a `didSet` observer:

```
var array: [MyStruct] {
    didSet {
        // do something with array and/or oldValue
    }
}
```

This will be called every time the array or one of its elements is mutated.

Comment: You're right. I tried that a few years ago and incorrectly remembered that it was called on setting the array but not modifying it. I should have just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Ole is right. FWIW Here's how I tested it

```
struct MyStruct : CustomStringConvertible {
    var thing = "thing"

    init(_ s:String) {
        print("struct \(#function)")
        thing = s
    }
    var description:String {
        get {
            return "\(thing)"
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    var a:[MyStruct] {
        didSet {
            print("didSet: a was set \(a)")
        }
    }

    init() {
        print("class \(#function)")
        a = [MyStruct("from Init")]
    }

    func blammo() {
        print("\(#function)")
        print("adding")
        a.append(MyStruct("Added"))
        print("new a \(a)")
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.blammo()
```